# What is the best way to create customized Windows Form controls?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making C# Windows Form application that has many forms that use many textboxes and labels of the same properties and style.
Instead of changing properties of every textbox and every label I created class called `MyTextBox` that inherits from `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` and then changed its properties in class constructor like this:

```
class MyTextBox:TextBox
{
    public MyTextBox()
    {
        this.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Bookman Old Style", 11F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(257, 23);
    }
}
```

After building project class appeared in toolbox and by making instances from this class on my form it worked fine.
The problem is that when I change any of the properties in `MyTextBox` class and rebuilding project, changes do not apply to the already instanced objects and when I looked at the designer code, I found that the IDE copied all properties from `MyTextBox` class to the designer code so I have to recreate all my instances after any change to class code.

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.MyTextBox1 = new WindowsFormsApplication9.MyTextBox();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // MyTextBox1
    // 
    this.MyTextBox1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    this.MyTextBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Bookman Old Style", 11F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
    this.MyTextBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    this.MyTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(67, 43);
```

Any way to solve this problem?  I want any changes to the class code applied to all already instanced objects without need to recreate them or if there is a better way please help.

Suppose I need to be controlling 5 properties of `MyTextBox` instance like `ForeColor`,default `Width`, default Font `Style` , default Font `size` and `BorderStyle`. All of them except `Width` property are not supposed to have other value than default value.

Comment: You could set the properties in an overriden `OnCreateControl`.  That code should run after the designer generated code.  But keep in mind that anything you set in the designer will get overwritten by these properties.

Comment: Upon further research it looks like `OnCreateControl` runs *before* `InitializeComponent` of the parent form, so that won't work. I don't see any control level events that are automatically raised *after* `InitializeComponent` of the parent.  I'm sure some kind of messaging system could be setup to trigger something in the controls to run, but that feels messy, I don't know if you want to go that route.

Comment: You have to open up each form that contains an extended control. The designer files for all forms are not updated when you change a property in code or the IDE, however, when you open a form it updates based on the latest build of the class.

Comment: @Bradely I think there may be an easier way

Comment: @Irb I don't understand what you mean exactly by opening form as i tried a lot of things like this but they didn't work

Comment: One of the things you typically need to do when you create your own control class from an existing one is to replace the base class properties.  And give them a new [DefaultValue] property.  Either use the *override* or the *new* keyword.

Comment: There are multiple solutions for such requirement.  **(1)** How many properties do you want to have in common and What are those properties exactly? **(2)** What are controls which you want to have common properties? **(3)** Do you want to have some common properties between all controls or common properties of your `TextBox` controls may be different with common properties of `Button` controls? **(4)** Is it enough if your controls appear with your theme settings only at run-time? **(5)** Do you need to change them at run-time?

Comment: @RezaAghaei 
(1) these are not only properties but also may be some similar methods e.g. some customized validation methods  . there are many properties that i could use ,not certain number
(2) Controls are mainly Textboxes, Labels and images
(3) Common properties of myTextBox controls will be different with common properties of Button controls
(4) I want these changes to appear at design time so some little modifications can be done to some of them to override common properties
(5) maybe i need to change some of them at run-time but that isn't the big issue

Comment: @RezaAghaei When trying to override for example ForeColor property of Textbox IDE gave error "can't change access modifier when overriding public inherited member"

Comment: When overriding, you can not change access modifier. What's your goal?

Comment: @RezaAghaei I have a class named "MyTextBox" inheriting from TextBox. I want to change the default Font , ForeColor Properties for this class so when making instances from this class in my project , all changes are applied to all instances without the need to recreate instances every change

Comment: I see. Do you need your text box control also be able to have it's own `ForeColor`? For example suppose `MyTextBox` has `ForeColor` with default value of `Color.Color1`. Then you put a `MyTextBox` on `Form1` and change its `ForeColor` to `Color.Color2`. Then After a while you decide to change default value for `ForeColor` to be `Color.Color3`. Know here is my questions: **(1)** Is changing `ForeColor` from default value supported?  **(2)** What is the value of `ForeColor` of `Form1` after you changed the default valuTextBox` to `Color.Color3`?

Comment: Well, suppose i need to be controlling 5 properties of MyTextBox  instance like ForeColor,default Width, default Font Style , default Font size and BorderStyle.All of them except Width property are not supposed to have other value than default value. So in your example for ForeColor the value for would be Color.Color3 but for Width it would be 2nd value

Comment: I'll go with 2 properties `A` and `B` which `A` is unchangeable. So `A` can not be changed in instances and always has the default value. But about `B`, it has a default value which if you don't touch it in instances, changing the default value in class will result in change the value in all instances with untouched value. But if in an instance you changed `B`, then changing default value will not result in change of `B` in that specific instance. Is it OK?

Comment: Sure, that would be exactly what i want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should provide suitable default values for properties in constructor. Then you should override or shadow properties and decorate them with one of these attributes:

- [`[DefaultValue]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)
  The designer will serialize these properties only if the value of theme is different than the default value which you set in the attribute.
- [`[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)
  The designer will not serialize values of these properties.

**Code**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public partial class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public MyTextBox()
    {
        this.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        this.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 9, FontStyle.Italic);
        this.Width = 200;
    }

    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Red")]
    public override Color ForeColor
    {
        get { return base.ForeColor; }
        set { base.ForeColor = value; }
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public override Font Font
    {
        get { return base.Font; }
        set { base.Font = value; }
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public new Size Size
    {
        get { return base.Size; }
        set { base.Size = value; }
    }
}
```

In the above example, I created a custom `TextBox` having these features:

- The default value for `ForeColor` is `Color.Red`. If you change value of `ForeColor` in instances of the control, the value will be serialized. If you change the default value in class, only those instances which their `ForeColor` was untouched will use new default value, other instances will use their `ForeColor` value.
- The default value for `Font` is `new Font("Tahoma", 9, FontStyle.Italic)` and since we said to the designer to not serialize `Font` property, the new value for property will not be saved if you change the value of different instances and all instances will use default value which is set in constructor of `MyTextBox`.
- For setting default `Width` which user can not change it using designer, I overrided `Size` and said the designer to not serialize it, so the width will be set to the default `Width` which I set in constructor.

Comment: Works fine but there is a problem. after building the project creating more instances of MyTextBox makes the designer to save current value of ForeColor in the form desinger code and so any change in the MyTextBox class code doesn't apply. Similarly that happens when changing ForeColor value of one of the instances, the desinger saves current value of allinstances not only the affected one

Comment: By setting `[DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Red")]` for the `ForeColor` property and `this.ForeColor = Color.Red;` in constructor, we made it to work this way: **1** If you change the `ForeColor` of an instance, the value will be serialized and will not pay attention to default value anymore. **2** If you change the default value in your control (both in attribute and in constructor), all controls that their `ForeColor` property was untouched will use new default value.

Comment: The main point of the answer is in the first paragraph and if you read it carefully you can decide what to do with properties.

Comment: Yes this works great. Thanks a lot. It was my mistake i didn't change the value in the constrcutor and the attribute in the same time so it somehow made the problem, but when changing them in the same time it worked very fine and stable. Thanks a lot for your patience. You are genius !

Answer (score 0):

A settings file should do what you want.  Create a new settings file in your project, if one doesn't exist already, and add a new setting like this:

[image]

then in your custom `TextBox` override `OnCreateControl`

```
protected override void OnCreateControl() {
    base.OnCreateControl();
    ForeColor = Settings.Default.TextBox_ForeColor;
}
```

Now you can change `ForeColor` in the settings file and the changes will cascade to all instances of your custom `TextBox`.  Follow the same pattern for `Font`, `Size`, etc, just be sure to set the correct `Type` in the settings file.